# EF Core DbContext erroring in AKS, but not locally in container

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core

I have a simple console application that's updating a database (Db is hosted in Azure).  I'm manually configuring the DbContext like this:

```
var options = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<MyContext>();            
var myContext = new MyContext(options);         
var myRepository = new MyRepository(myContext);
```

MyContext looks like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer( ... );
    }
}
```

I compile this and run it inside a container locally and it works fine.  However, as soon as I add the image to an AKS cluster, I start getting the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: No database
>   provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be
>   configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by
>   using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If
>   AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
>   accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
>   passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider
>   scopedProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() 
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges(Object
>   entity)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(Object entity,
>   EntityState entityState)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add(Object entity)    at

As far as I can see, I've done exactly what it's suggesting; although the thing that I really don't understand it why it behaves differently inside AKS.  Can anyone shed some light on this for me, please?

Comment: I would normally pass conenction string in Startup.cs rather than in Context class.    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("mydbstring"))); Not susre if this will make any difference

Comment: It's a console application, so I don't have the Asp.Net Core infrastructure.

Comment: @SmileyDev Show your full code of `UseSqlServer( ... );`

Comment: Since it just has the connection string in, I'm not sure that would be useful

Comment: is the connection string same for both local and AKS?